# Error al consultar imágenes de tipo LONGBLOB en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando con una insercción de tres imágenes hacía una Base de Datos en mysql la cual esta compuesta por los siguientes campos:

```
idFoto, id_registro, foto1c foto2, foto3
```

"idRegistro" funge como llave foranea de otra tabla de registros que solo guarda información varchar. Dichas insercciones funcionan perfectamente  y las imágenes se guardan en formato ~LONGBLOB~ y al mismo tiempo se almacenan en una carpeta en el servidor, NO ESTOY ALMACENANDO LA RUTA. El código para insertar las imágenes es el siguiente:

```
include("conexion.php");
$id_registro = $_POST['id_registro'];

//aqui van las imagenes (Carpeta o ruta que usaras)
$path = "imagenes/";
//$directorio = opendir("$path");

//Hacemos un poco de código verificando que se recibieron las imagenes
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){

//almacenamos las propiedades de las imagenes
$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

//recorremos el array de imagenes para subirlas al simultaneo
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "imagenes/".$name_array[$i])){

        //guardamos en la base de datos el nombre
        $act = "INSERT INTO imagenes (id_registro,foto1,foto2,foto3) values ('$id_registro','$name_array[0]','$name_array[1]','$name_array[2]')";
        if($mysqli->query($act)){
          echo "<img src='".$path.$name_array[$i]."'> Las imágenes fueron subidas exitosamente.<br>";

    }
    else
    {
        //si ocurrio algun problema entonces
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
}}
```

El problema es que necesito consultar las imágenes pero no me esta regresando una de las imágenes con la codificación. Alguna recomendación???
El código de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$mostrarFicha = Ficha ($_GET['id_registro']);
function Ficha($id_registro)
{
include 'conexion.php';

$sentencia = "SELECT * FROM registros R INNER JOIN imagenes I ON R.id_registro = I.id_registro WHERE R.id_registro = '{$_GET['id_registro']}' ORDER BY R.id_registro ASC";

$resultado= $mysqli->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al consultar registro.".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();

<img src="data:imagenes/png;base64, '.base64_encode($mostrarFicha['foto1']).'">
```

Comment: ¿El problema es con una de las imágenes, no con todas? ¿Esa imagen cumple realmente con la condición del `JOIN`?

Comment: La consulta del Join la utilizo para juntar los datos de otra tabla que tiene información ya que no solo traigo imágenes sino datos, como lo indiqué al inicio. El problema es con  las 3 imágenes.

Comment: La pregunta está planteada de forma confusa al leer esto: *`...pero no me esta regresando una de las imágenes con la codificación...`* se entiende que tienes problema con una de las imágenes. Tampoco se entiende a qué te refieres cuando hablas de *codificación*. Por favor aclara la pregunta y dinos cuál es el código que debemos revisar, de ese modo podremos ayudarte mejor.